# How to install PSQL driver for PHP 7.2

Tags: drivers, php, postgresql

I am trying to install Postresql driver for PHP, but when I run

```
apt-get install php7.2-pqsql
```

I am getting following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.2-pgsql : Depends: php7.2-common (= 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 7.2.14-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
```

When I run:

```
apt-get install php7.2-common
```

I am getting:

```
php7.2-common is already the newest version (7.2.14-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
```

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: It seems: that you mean `php7.2-pgsql` package and that you are using PHP PPA. Please add output of `apt-cache policy php7.2-pgsql php7.2-common` to the question.